# WSL2 OpenSUSE - Getting XFCE to work

Tags: x11, xfce, opensuse, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been using OpenSUSE-Tumbleweed on WSL2 and tried to implement XFCE. However, when I run `startxfce4`, the following is shown and XFCE doesn't start:

```
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display <IP-ADDRESS>:0.0

(xfce4-session:700): dbind-WARNING **: 20:06:11.793: AT-SPI: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
Segmentation fault
```

The `.bashrc` file has the following configuration so that `<IP-ADDRESS>` is set to the local IP-Address in `$DISPLAY`:

```
export DISPLAY=$(grep -m 1 nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}'):0.0
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
```

As for packages, I've installed the patterns `wsl_gui`, `wsl_base`, `wsl_systemd`, `xfce` and `xrdp`, as well as `xterm` and `rhythmbox` to test GUI-programs outside of XFCE.
The X-Server I'm using on Windows is VcXsrv.

Weirdly enough, the latter two GUI-Apps already do work. `rhythmbox` works flawlessly on a separate window (and not on VcXsrv), albeit with following warning on the terminal:

```
(rhythmbox:4609): dbind-WARNING **: 20:29:03.995: AT-SPI: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
```

I conclude that this dbind-warning is probably irrelevant, both for `rhythmbox` and `startxfce4`.

Furthermore, I think there should also be nothing wrong with the firewall settings between WSL2 and VcXsrv or the `$DISPLAY` variable, as `xterm` works perfectly fine on the VcXsrv server, without any warnings shown in the terminal.

After some digging, I found this post on reddit on this topic: https://www.reddit.com/r/openSUSE/comments/hzmo3i/a_solution_for_x_on_opensuse_on_wsl2/

I should have followed all those steps through, the only thing I'm not so sure of is whether I've got all necessary packages installed. However, guides on the matter of implementing a desktop environment on WSL2 more or less just install `xfce` and `xrdp`, as far as I have seen (though they are mostly about Ubuntu, that is). After skimming through yast and zypper's package list, I also wouldn't have seen something particular that could be helpful, but I can be easily mistaken about that. I would be really grateful if somebody knows why XFCE doesn't want to start.